# How to display Python file header description

Tags: python, comments

I was wondering if you knew how to run a python file to only display the file description. 
For example I have these lines on the top of my python program.

```
"""
===================================================
    test.py
    sphchow

    Description
====================================================
"""
```

I want to be able to run it so it displays this. But also have the ability to run the program normally. I tried searching around and could only find information like `__docstring__` I think I'm not using the right key words?

Comment: `__docstring__` is the name of the lines at the top of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your module is `foo.py` then you can do:

```
import foo
print(foo.__doc__)
```

This will print the [docstring](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring) for the module.

Or from the command line:

```
python -c "import foo; print(foo.__doc__)"
```

As mentioned in the comments, this information is also displayed when you use the help command:

```
help(foo)
```

Comment: You can also access it through `import foo; help(foo)`, which will give you other information as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was exactly what I was looking for